# Gelatinous Cube damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, damage

This seems really basic, but I'm not really sure how to treat the case where a creature has been engulfed by a gelatinous cube. Does the creature simply take 1d6 acid damage as if it were attacked, or 10d6 for being completely immersed in acid?

Answer (score 10):

Swallowed creatures take 1d6 acid damage each round they're engulfed.  They're not completely immersed in acid, they're being slowly digested.

Comment: Yeah, seems pretty clear by the GC description - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/oozes/gelatinous-cube